# Which number is bigger?

Tags: code-golf, math, fastest-algorithm

Define `f(a,b) := a if b=1; a^f(a,b-1) if b>1` ([Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration), where `^` means power) for positive integers `a` and `b`, given four positive integers `a,b,c,d`, compare `f(a,b)` and `f(c,d)`.

Your program should output three constant values to mean "greater", "less" and "equal".

Samples:

```
a b c d f(a,b) output f(c,d)
3 2 2 3 27     >      16
4 2 2 4 256    <      65536
4 1 2 2 4      =      4
```

Lowest time complexity to `max{a,b,c,d}` win, with tie-breaker code length(the shorter the better) and then answer time(the earlier the better).

### Complexity assumption

- Your code should handle `a,b,c,d` up to 100, and your algorithm should handle all legal input
- You can assume integer calculations (that your language directly support) in `O((a+b+c+d)^k)` cost `O(1)` time if can be done in O(1) for 2k bit numbers if k bit computing can be done in O(1)
- For example, both plus(`+`) and multiply(`*`) can be done in O(1) for 2k bit numbers if k bit computing for both can be done in O(1), so both satisy the requirement. It's fine if multiply can't be done without plus, or even if both can't be done without each other.
- Float calculations in `O(log(a+b+c+d))` bit precision in `±2^O((a+b+c+d)^k)`, takes `O(1)`, with same requirements like integer calculations.

Comment: [tag:code-golf] and [tag:fastest-algorithm] are conflicting with each other.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer `Fastest-algorithm challenges often result in ties, because the number of different complexities if often rather limited for certain problems, and once an optimal solution has been found there is a good chance others will be posted. For these cases, a tie-breaker should always be specified. Common choices are earliest answer, shortest code-length of the given implementation or shortest actual runtime on a given problem set.`

Comment: Do any of these rules prevent a lookup table from being used?

Comment: @user2699 `and your algorithm should handle all legal input`, `if k bit computing can be done in O(1)` (time, space & code)

Comment: Can you clarify how complexity is measured?  Your comment mentions time and space, while Big-O notation measures approximate running time, but the description also seems to include individual floating point operations.

Comment: @l4m2 I think [tag:code-challenge] is more applicable than two separate tags here, since those two tags each mean that the criterion they describe is absolutely the only one, and, if I search for [tag:code-golf] challenges, I won't expect to find a challenge with a winning criterion like this one's.

Comment: Tetration is actually defined with `a if b=0` as the base case, not b=1 as in the challenge. Is this intentional?

Comment: @hakr14 The definition in wiki is `1 if b=0`, but I don't require handle of zero, so it's `a if b=1`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I see some posts put all layers of winning criticia as tag and some put only the first, but code-challenge mean the combination of bother affect the rank together, rather than one first and another as tie-breaking

Comment: Usually a primary win-condition tag is used (`[fastest-algorithm]` in this case), and the challenge itself states what to do on tie-breakers without an additional tag. I definitely understand why you've added the `[code-golf]` tag as tie-breaker. Once an efficient algorithm is found, others might copy it, or the amount of algorithms to be used is limited from the beginning maybe. But as mentioned by _@EriktheOutgolfer_, when I search for code-golf challenges, I wouldn't expect these kind of challenges to pop up.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Once an efficient algorithm is found, others might copy it, and it will turn into a [tag:restricted-complexity] [tag:code-golf]

Comment: @l4m2 Tie breakers are in the criterion too, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 295 bytes

```java
int f(Long a,long b,long c,long d){return a>c?-f(c,d,a,b):a<c?b>d?d==1?(a==2&((b==2&c==4)|(b==3&c==16)))|(a==3&b==2&c==27)?0:1:b-d>1?1:f(t(a,b),1,c,d):-1:a<2?0:a.signum(b-d);}long t(long a,long b){long t=1;for(;b-->0;)t=p(a,t);return t;}long p(long a,long b){long p=1;for(;b-->0;)p*=a;return p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFNb9swDL33VxAdUkiDbEROsAH2FAO7FehOPQY5yJ@TF8uGzXQYUv/2jJKSrigGw6Qe@fhIUZ1@0VFX/bqYfhwmhI5w3Gv8GX837aPFuq2n7K486nmGH9pYON8BjKfiaEqYUSO5l8FU0FOOPeNkbLs/gJ7amXsqhKoeFNj6tweMZz5xHByX2FjPOBMh8AHOG5HQt1nELbD1ge37gHShxeMl6HnTDBMLwoBpUOZvws9/Zqz7eDhhPNKkeLSsjxuG@/VBAO6lt4m3mwO/jul6uP/9bbHGidBgGamAEeBcd2v0sU3D7lcVfAIyiszKruy9MKIT/zYSI6NAaOmaXZxgw57oJqCFuxAUwZXBVfw81XiaLOhdmUcNK0UltCh4qr@VebGr8kopmTOtVPLAWOFcqdSWv7rzxp3lF84Jagdv@eQrz9epTIuo2slcprQc5lRp3dSAp5Ek/YQoOp5Na089IybPFj8T@s2/zcvPIapk5l4lK6Jot844qpEkkWfX@fFaPf63evxQPX5W@lY5ZstlufwF)

Codes:

- `1` if `a^^b > c^^d`
- `-1` if `a^^b < c^^d`
- `0` is `a^^b == c^^d`

Comment: fail on `{1,4,2,2}`?

Comment: I'll fix later today. I must have switched two conditions when golfing.

Comment: [159 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVDLbsMgELz3K1apIkGFrTjJKdSJ1FsPPeUY5YDxo7g2tvAmVWX521MeTZNWiBl2GHaAWpxFVOcfF9X2nUGobR23At/jF1W9aiyqwvAH2YhhgDehNIwPAP0pa5SEAQVaOncqh9bukT0apavDEYSpBuqtEE61kIIuPn1BKPcbTee81o3FgIM1BD/AuGJLO1YTuwprL6zvhcRJNyFh3jP5egoBHsrOkJAEuAlR9Ddp/zVg0cbdCePeXh0bTdq4JHhYHBngIfG49Lg60p97uww375@PBRpbdZrYLqAYOKqvQf9jSjKb5/AIFlILcz3XM6ZYzW5fFCOxQoh0YRfXsPQvAcE8ZYFkoJyOIkUiWEa5tAvJcspNgSejQWzlLtmIZ7mLks2CT/4A/m1Gx6CmCeuZ5O7beBZF2wWnbt1b3bblMkiY9k@puPZHPl2myzc "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>30</s> 19 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{f←*/⍴⍨⋄×(f/⍺)-f/⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///vzrtUdsELf1HvVse9a541N1yeLpGGpC3S1MXRG2t/Z@uAFSgAFZWDRSwNbQCygIVAkktEKujHSiqa1iLRS8X16O@qSDdxgpGCulAbAwTMIEKmCAEDMECRv8B) Thanks to @ngn for saving 11 bytes by defining tetration in a much clever and shorter way:

```apl
f ← */⍴⍨   ⍝ Define f to be the tetration function
       ⍨   ⍝ Taking a on the right and b on the left, 
      ⍴    ⍝   creating an array of b occurrences of the number a
    */     ⍝ and then building the tower of exponentials.
```

Now if I have a vector with two integers, `f/` applies the function to those two integers, e.g. `f/ 2 4` gives `65536` and `f/ 4 2` gives `256`. We need this in our main function:

```apl
{f←*/⍴⍨⋄×(f/⍺)-f/⍵}  ⍝ Dyadic function (g) expecting two vectors of 2 integers, e.g. 4 2 g 2 4
{f←*/⍴⍨            }  ⍝ Define the auxiliar function as above
{      ⋄           }  ⍝ and then:
{              f/⍵}   ⍝ Apply aux function to the right vector of integers
{        (f/⍺)     }  ⍝ Apply aux function to the left vector of integers
{             -    }  ⍝ Subtract the two values and finally
{       ×          }  ⍝ get the sign of that difference.
```

This means my function returns 1 if the left integers give a larger value, 0 if they are the same or ¯1 if the left integers give a smaller value.

My original submission had a recursive definition of tetration:

```apl
{f←{⍵=1:⍺⋄⍺*⍺∇⍵-1}⋄×(f/⍺)-f/⍵}
```

with tetration as:

```apl
{               }  ⍝ Dyadic function expecting 2 integers
{⍵=1:⍺         }  ⍝ If the right argument is 1, return the left argument;
{      ⋄        }  ⍝ otherwise (separate previous statement from the next one)
{       ⍺*      }  ⍝ Take the left argument to the power of
{         ⍺∇⍵-1}  ⍝ the recursive call of this function with same left argument and decremented right argument.
```

Comment: "Your code should handle a,b,c,d up to 100"

Comment: @ngn isn't it standard to assume I get arbitrary precision? Or what am I missing here?

Comment: maybe. other answers violate this requirement too. the challenge is unclear.

Comment: assuming arbitrary precision, tetration can be `*/⍴⍨`

Comment: I thought the challenge was to figure out how to compare \$f(a,b)\$ with \$f(c,d)\$ for input values up to \$100\$, without actually computing those values (since doing the actual computations isn't feasible).  I think that's an interesting challenge!  (If we were allowed to pretend that we could compute \$f(a,b)\$ and \$f(c,d)\$ so we could then just compare them with an if statement, it wouldn't be very interesting.)

Comment: I think the challenge should state (or should have stated) that any input with values up to 100 needs to be processed by TIO within its one-minute time limit, or something comparable for languages not offered by TIO.  (I presume this is possible, but I haven't worked on a solution.)

Comment: @MitchellSpector that was not what I understood from it, partly because I can read the Haskell solution and it does more or less the same as me. I can't read the java one too well but it feels like it also computes tetration

Comment: @ngn that is a nice golf

Comment: I agree that that’s how it’s being interpreted, and it really wasn’t spelled out in the challenge. In any case, once there are answers, the challenge really shouldn’t be changed.

Comment: @MitchellSpector alright... To sum up, and to check if I got it right, you think me and nimi misinterpreted the challenge but because nimi's answer is so old we can't really make the challenge more clear?

Comment: @RGS  I don't think anybody misinterpreted it -- the challenge was just underspecified. And, actually, Olivier Grégoire's Java solution presumably wins in any case (since this challenge is fastest-algorithm with tie-breakers).

Comment: In 18.0: `×-⍥(*/¨⍴⍨/)`

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 46 bytes

```
a#1=a
a#b=a^a#(b-1)
(a!b)c d=compare(a#b)(c#d)
```

Prints `GT` for `>`,  `LT` for `<` and `EQ`for `=`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vck7DoMwEAXA3qd4lil2ixQ2dJGvEunZRgLxFcn9nUQ00M4MfE/9PNdK5yOfdCnyRSfp4dUIbdKMEvO27Dx6@bVKdkXrwnFFRNkMsB/j@kEDaW1QBLRX607r7ub/FuoX)